# Drawing markers with custom SQL in javascript with carto

Tags: postgresql, javascript, carto

I am trying to draw markers with custom psql using the js `cartobd.createLayer` method. The below snippet doesn’t throw any errors, but doesn’t draw any markers on the map either.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: [40.7128,-74.0059],
    zoom: 14
  });
  var layer = L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/fluffywolf24/cimhxr71f0021qxno7nts1d4w', { detectRetina: true });
  layer.addTo(map);
  console.log('map:', map);
  cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: 'whayler1',
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [{
      sql: "SELECT * FROM ny_listings",
      cartocss: '#map {marker-fill: #F0F0F0;}'
    }]
  })
  .addTo(map)
  .done(function(layer) {
    console.log('done', layer);
    // create and add a new sublayer
    layer.createSubLayer({
      sql: "SELECT * FROM ny_listings",
      cartocss: '#map {marker-fill: #000000;}'
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the rest of the code and the errors you are getting is difficult to understand what is going on. Anyway, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/83aab20206e8b870b92f5b7fd9ad1b3f) you have a working example using the part you are shared with us. Basically, I have commented the lines of code you use `mapbox` API, and in its place, I have added a Leaflet map:

```
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'OpenStreetMaps'
    }).addTo(map);
```

The rest is the same, well I have changed a little bit the style of the markers. :-)